# arrays elements to dataframe columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

```
recipe_id   cuisine     ingredients
0   10259   greek       [romaine lettuce, black olives, grape tomatoes]
1   25693   southern_us [plain flour, ground pepper, salt, tomatoes]
2   20130   filipino    [eggs, pepper, salt, mayonaise, cooking oil]
3   22213   indian      [water, vegetable oil, wheat, salt]
```

Dataframe has a column, which contains arrays with different ingredients for each recipe per row.
My goal is to create column for each and every ingredient; mark with 1, if corresponding ingredient is used in recipe row, and 0 if not.

My solution is:

```
for index,item in enumerate(df.ingredients):
  for ingredient in item:
    if (ingredient not in df.columns): df[ingredient]=0
    df[ingredient].iloc[index]=1
```

But exercise answer suggests:

```
def find_item(cell):
    if i in cell:
        return 1
    return 0

for item in df.ingredients:
  for i in item:
    df[i] = df['ingredients'].apply(find_item)
```

Result is the same. My solution seems more readable to me.
I'd like to find out the reasons to do it with apply.

P.S. Also I get a warning with my solution, but can't find out, how should I fix it?

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

data is available here:

```
import urllib.request, json, urllib
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/konst54/datasets/master/recipes.json") as url:
    recepies = json.loads(url.read().decode())
df=pd.DataFrame(recepies)
```

Comment: `df[ingredient].iloc[index]=1`, which triggers the warngin, is index chaining and should be avoid.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks, I got that, but what will be the right way to address specific cell in this context?

Comment: Again, in general, I would strongly advise loopling, but in your case, you can do: `df.loc[df.index[index], ingredient] = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error you get that @Quang Hoang said:

> `df[ingredient].iloc[index]=1`, which triggers the warning, is index chaining and should be avoid.

As another option, to your solutions, also you can try this, using some `pivot` and `explode`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
#creating your dataframe
s_e='''
recipe_id      cuisine        ingredients
0   10259     greek         ['romaine', 'lettuce', 'black olives', 'grape tomatoes']
1   25693     southern_us     ['plain flour', 'ground pepper', 'salt', 'tomatoes']
2   20130     filipino      ['eggs', 'pepper', 'salt', 'mayonaise', 'cooking oil']
3   22213     indian        ['water', 'vegetable oil', 'wheat', 'salt']
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s_e), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df.ingredients=df.ingredients.apply(eval)
print(df)


#approach to solution
df=df.explode('ingredients')
df['val']=[1]*len(df.ingredients)
newdf=df.pivot(index='recipe_id', columns='ingredients', values='val').fillna(0)
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
df
   recipe_id      cuisine                                       ingredients
0      10259        greek  [romaine, lettuce, black olives, grape tomatoes]
1      25693  southern_us      [plain flour, ground pepper, salt, tomatoes]
2      20130     filipino      [eggs, pepper, salt, mayonaise, cooking oil]
3      22213       indian               [water, vegetable oil, wheat, salt]



newdf
ingredients  black olives  cooking oil  eggs  grape tomatoes  ground pepper  lettuce  mayonaise  pepper  plain flour  romaine  salt  tomatoes  vegetable oil  water  wheat
recipe_id
10259                 1.0          0.0   0.0             1.0            0.0      1.0        0.0     0.0          0.0      1.0   0.0       0.0            0.0    0.0    0.0
20130                 0.0          1.0   1.0             0.0            0.0      0.0        1.0     1.0          0.0      0.0   1.0       0.0            0.0    0.0    0.0
22213                 0.0          0.0   0.0             0.0            0.0      0.0        0.0     0.0          0.0      0.0   1.0       0.0            1.0    1.0    1.0
25693                 0.0          0.0   0.0             0.0            1.0      0.0        0.0     0.0          1.0      0.0   1.0       1.0            0.0    0.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping is one option, but if you consider speed and maintenance, you might consider this option as well.

```
df = df.explode('ingredients').reset_index(drop=True)
df['cnt'] = 1

gb = df.groupby(['id','cuisine','ingredients'])['cnt'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)

gb
```

[image]